# How an interface is passed as reference

Tags: java, interface, reference

I have a doubt, following is the code for the `bufferedwriter`

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(testcasename+".html"));
```

Constructor of `BufferedWriter` accepts only parameter of reference type 'Writer' abstract class, how does '`filewriter`' class is instantiated in the above code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean.

But you did `new FileWriter(path`) which creates a `FileWriter` instance and `FileWriter` extends `Writer` which makes it perfectly valid.

`Writer` isn't an interface but an **abstract class** that can be **extended** or **subclassed** etc.

Interfaces are **implemented**. And `new` creates an object and returns a **pointer** or **reference** to that object. The reference is **passed by value** into the `BufferedWriter` constructor (think of a constructor as a special method) which accepts a `Writer` object.

I really hope my explanation made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

FileWriter IS A Writer, as it extends the Writer abstract class (although not directly). Therefore it can be treated as a Writer. Please see:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

Hint : object of child class can be type cast to parent class but not vice-versa.

in case above , you get an object of class Filewriter , which extends class Writer hence valid.